# How to use DispatchSemaphore with Alamofire and SwiftyJSON?

Tags: json, swift, asynchronous, swifty-json

I was trying to use some json response outside the method but it returns empty array when method is executed, but inside the block works as expected, is there any way my method will return expected value, here is my sample code:

```
func getCarouselContent(url: String) -> [String] {
    var ids: [String] = []
    let headers = ["api_key": "My_API_KEY"]

    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    Alamofire.request(url, headers: headers).validate().responseJSON { 
        (response) in
        semaphore.signal()
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            let json = JSON(value)
            let data = json["data"]["relationships"]["slides"]["data"]
            for child in data.array! {
                let id = child["id"].string!
                print(id) // this prints all the id
                ids.append(id)
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
    semaphore.wait()
    return ids 
}
```

I am using alamofire and swiftyjson to parse the json. FYI I am new to this and tried solutions from the response of similar questions but didn't work, any advice is highly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gonna address your original issue *then* provide a better solution:

**Semaphores**. You might be firing your signal too soon. A robust idiom for safely signaling a `DispatchSemaphore`, when returning from a function/closure, is to use the `defer` statement. For instance:

```
Alamofire.request(url, headers: headers).validate().responseJSON {    
    (response) in {
    defer { 
        semaphore.signal() // Executed before leaving current scope.
    } 
    ...
}
```

this ensures you *always* fires `signal()` independently of your exit point, avoiding deadlocks.

*Having said that, this might be far from the best solution...*

**Completion handlers**. You designed your `getCarouselContent` method to *block* the calling code until a network request is done, which might take a (very!) long time. *If* you are planning to call this method from your app *main thread* this will certainly result in a very bad UX. Let's see what [Apple says about this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTips/PerformanceTips.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW19):

> Be sure to limit the type of work you do on the main thread of your app. The main thread is where your app handles touch events and other user input. To ensure that your app is always responsive to the user, you should never use the main thread to perform long-running or potentially unbounded tasks, such as tasks that access the network. Instead, you should always move those tasks onto background threads.

A common pattern around this is to pass a *completion block* to your `getCarouselContent` method. This block would then be passed the result when the JSON response finally arrives. For instance:

```
func getCarouselContent(url: String, completion: @escaping ([String]) -> Void) {
    let headers = ["api_key": "My_API_KEY"]
    Alamofire.request(url, headers: headers).validate().responseJSON { 
        (response) in
        var ids = [String]()
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            let json = JSON(value)
            let data = json["data"]["relationships"]["slides"]["data"]
            for child in data.array! {
                ids.append(child["id"].string!)
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
        completion(ids)
    }
}
```

and call it like this:

```
getCarouselContent(url: someUrl) {
    (ids) in 
    print("IDs received: \(ids)")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Forget semaphores to work around the asynchronous behavior of a method. Learn to understand the asynchronous pattern and use a completion handler:

```
func getCarouselContent(url: String, completion: ([String])->())  {
       var ids = [String]()
       let headers = ["api_key": "My_API_KEY"]

        Alamofire.request(url, headers: headers).validate().responseJSON{ response in
           switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                let json = JSON(value)

                let data = json["data"]["relationships"]["slides"]["data"]
                for child in data.array! {
                    let id = child["id"].string!
                    print(id) // this prints all the id
                    ids.append(id)
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
            completion(ids)
        }
}
```

And call it:

```
getCarouselContent(url: <someURL>) { identifiers in

    print(identifiers)
}
```